# Unable to upload file through react frontend

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, cloudinary, rtk-query

I am trying to upload the image from React Frontend to Cloudinary. I wrote a backend API called upload image. when I try through Postman it works fine the files are uploaded to Cloudinary Server but when I try through my React it shows the file not received. It really helps if anyone go through this code I share tell me the mistake I am making and why my backend is not getting the file.

### dataUri.js

```
import DataUriParser from "datauri/parser.js";
import path from "path";

const getDataURI = (file) => {
    const parser = new DataUriParser();
    const extName = path.extname(file.originalname).toString();
    return parser.format(extName, file.buffer);
};

export default getDataURI;
```

### multerMiddleware.js

**which I use in the route**

```
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

const singleUpload = multer({ storage }).single("file");

export default singleUpload;
```

### My Image Controller

```
export const uploadImagesUrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const field = req.params.field;
        try {
            const file = req.file;

            if (!file) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file received" });
            }

            const fileURI = getDataURI(file);

            const imgUpload = await cloudinaryConfig();

            const { cloud_name } = imgUpload.config();

            const result = await imgUpload.uploader.upload(fileURI.content, {
                folder: "JewelryMine",
            });

            const image = await Image.findByIdAndUpdate(process.env.IMAGE_CONFIGURATION_ID);

            const image_url = `https://res.cloudinary.com/${cloud_name}/image/upload/${result.public_id}`;

            const updateObj = {
                $set: {
                    [`${field}.public_id`]: result.public_id,
                    [`${field}.image_url`]: image_url,
                },
            };

            if (image) {
                await image.updateOne(updateObj, options)
                return res.json({ message: "File Uploaded" });
            } else {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: "Field not found" });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Upload failed" });
        }

        //
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500);
        throw new Error("Server Error. Please try after sometime.");
    }
});
```

### And My React File

**form**

```
    <div className='mt-2'>
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
            <input type='file' accept='image/*' onChange={handleImage} required />
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <label >Preview</label>
          <img src={imgPreview} required />
        </div>
        <div className='mt-4'>
            <button type='submit'>Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**handleChange and handle Submit Part**

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [imgPreview, setImgPreview] = useState("");
const [updateImageUrl] = useUpdateImageUrlMutation();
    
    const handleImage = async (event) => {
        setImage(event.target.files[0]);
        const url = await URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0] || image);
        setImgPreview(url);
    };

    const submitHandler = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", image);

        try {
            const res = await updateImageUrl({ field, formData }).unwrap();

            if (res) {
                toast.success(res.message || res.data.message);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            toast.error(err?.data?.message || err?.error || err?.data?.error);
        }
    };
```

Comment: If you compare the request made from Postman vs the request your React frontend makes, what is the difference?

Comment: @Aleksandar req made from the frontend doesn't receive the file its shows the file not received but through Postman it perfectly uploads in server

Comment: @Aleksandar do you see any error in this code why the file is not reaching to backend through react- frontend

Comment: Right, but ("No file received") is on the server side. If you inspect the request that the frontend sends, is it actually sending the file and the server is then reporting it didn't receive it? Or does the frontend not send the file (in which case the server is returning the expected result)?

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the working request via Postman?

Comment: @Aleksandar I made console.log multiple places i don't if I console log the formData will I see the formData that I just append but i console log the image in submithandler i can the file in Image state so i appending in form data then i console log in controller in two part one is req.body and another is req.file in req.body part i don't see the formData is null and req.file shows undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255298/discussion-between-narayan-maity-and-aleksandar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating with an answer based on the chat discussion:

There were two issues:

1. When sending the file from the client side the `Content-Type` didn't match the data being sent (it likely defaulted to `application/json`) while the content was actually `multipart/form-data`. This caused the server not to be able to parse the request correctly.
2. The value of the `body` in the RTK query was containing both the `formData` and `field` based on the call to `updateImageUrl` inside `handleSubmit`.

The solution for 1) was to set `formData: true` in the RTK query and that will allow the `Content-Type` header to be set automatically to `multipart/form-data` as part of the request to match the data being sent.

For 2) the value of the `body` was set to `data.formData`.

The resulting RTK query with the above changes applied:

```
updateImageUrl: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${IMAGES_API_URL}/upload/${data.field}`,
                method: "PUT",
                formData: true,
                body: data.formData,
                // credentials: "include",
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Images"],
        }),
```